# Selecting multiple elements from array python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

this is a pretty basic question but here goes:

I would like to create an array and then would like to compare a user input to those elements within the array.

If one element is matched then function 1 would run. If two elements were matched in the array the an alternative function would run and so on and so forth.

Currently i can only use an IF statement with no links to the array as follows:

```
def stroganoff():
    print ("You have chosen beef stroganoff")
    return

def beef_and_ale_pie():
    print ("You have chosen a beef and ale pie")
    return

def beef_burger():
    print ("You have chosen a beef burger")
    return

ingredients = ['beef','mushrooms','ale','onions','steak','burger']

beef = input("Please enter your preferred ingredients ")

if "beef" in beef and "mushrooms" in beef:
    stroganoff()
elif "beef" in beef and "ale" in beef:
    beef_and_ale_pie()
elif "beef" in beef and "burger" in beef:
    beef_burger()
```

As said, this is basic stuff for some of you but thank you for looking!

Comment: By `array` do you mean `array` or `list`? As in python both are similar but different things. If you want list, you already have one `ingredients = ['beef','mushrooms','ale','onions','steak','burger']`. Please can you be little clear about your intentions here.

Comment: When i say array - i actually mean list! But I can't access the list to do what I want it to as described. It works as it is but I would like to be able to add to the list and have efficient coding to compare input with list and when two words are matched then run a particular function without having to have the long ELIF statement as it currently is . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you only can work with IF statements

```
beef=input().split()
#this splits all the characters when they're space separated
#and makes a list of them
```

you can use your `"beef" in beef and "mushrooms" in beef` and it should run as you expected it to

Answer (score 0):

So I understand your question such that you want to know, how many of your `ingredients` are entered by the user:

```
ingredients = {'beef','mushrooms','ale','onions','steak','burger'}

# assume for now the inputs are whitespace-separated:
choices = input("Please enter your preferred ingredients ").split()

num_matches = len(ingredients.intersection(choices))
print('You chose', num_matches, 'of our special ingredients.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like:

```
# Dictionary to map function to execute with count of matching words
check_func = {
    0: func_1,
    1: func_2,
    2: func_3,    
} 

ingredients = ['beef','mushrooms','ale','onions','steak','burger']
user_input = input()

# Convert user input string to list of words
user_input_list = user_input.split()

# Check for the count of matching keywords
count = 0
for item in user_input_list:
    if item in ingredients:
        count += 1

# call the function from above dict based on the count
check_func[count]()
```

Comment: Thank you however when I run this i get the following error message:    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Dan/Documents/Python/lists2.py", line 3, in <module>
    0: func_1,
NameError: name 'func_1' is not defined

Comment: What is the error message? And I believe that you have already defined `func_1 `, `func_2` functions  in your code or would have replaced these by your own functions in the `dict` :)

Comment: Exactly as what I thought. I just gave you the sample code. You have to replace these with your `stroganoff`, `beef_and_ale_pie ` or any other function you want. Note: function should be mentioned there without `()`

Comment: Hi again, it counts the number of elements but is there a way of either identifying the actual elements from the list - the key words, and/or automatically run the function. It currently only runs the beef_burger regardless of input.               for example; the user inputs beef and ale, the program says: we have identified the key words beef and ale;      then the program runs the beef_and_ale_pie function? Your help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I've figured out how to identify the keywords found but still considering how to run function automatically!

Comment: But in the question you mention `count`, right? In case of words, you can mention `tuple` of words as keys instead of count. For example `('beef', 'mushrooms')` <- This should be your key. Note: It will treat `('beef', 'mushrooms')` and `( 'mushrooms', 'beef')` as two different keys. So, before calling the `dict`, firstly sort the tuple and make the key in `dict` of sorted items, OR (not recommended) create multiple keys with all the combinations of words in the list, and map it to the desired function